# Sending data from Android App to Labview WebServer

Tags: android, networking, automation, android-networking, labview

I am trying to test the labview Webserver and would like to send data fron an android app to the server .

The data is just two simple hexacodes ;

How can I do it ?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Show what you have done, and where the trouble was

Comment: Have a look at https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-12716 - Building Android Applications for Simple Data Monitoring. Old, but useful document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run LabVIEW web application server. Than use LabVIEW RESTFUL Web service.

Here are good examples for that: 
http://chrislarson.me/blog/labview-web-services-restful-crud.html
http://www.ni.com/white-paper/7747/en/
http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361G-01/lvhowto/build_web_service/ (this would not work if you use LabVIEW 2012 or later)

For more you can go with LabVIEW connectivity course: http://www.ni.com/pdf/products/us/lv-int-ii-mkt-course-outline.pdf

Also there is way to use websocket. There is Websocket library under labVIEW.